# Read File (Memory Mapping) and then split the string into token

Tags: c++, string, token

I'm having a problem with this code that Visual Studio keeps reporting:

> Unhandled exception at 0x628D692E (msvcr120.dll) in Z Final Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00990004.

After reading a string from the file, I try to split it into tokens:

```
int main()
{
    HANDLE hFile , MapHandle;
    char * name = new char[20];
    char * word = new char[100];
    char * data , * MapPointer;
    strcpy_s(name , 10 , "d0000.txt");
    //List DocumentList;
    Trie document;
    clock_t start = clock();
    do
    {
        next_document(name , 4);
        hFile = CreateFileA(name , GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE , 0 , NULL , OPEN_EXISTING , FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS , NULL);
        MapHandle = CreateFileMapping(hFile , NULL , PAGE_READWRITE | SEC_RESERVE , 0 , 0 , 0);
        if (MapHandle == NULL)
        {
            CloseHandle(hFile);
            break;
        }
        cout << name << ": ";
        MapPointer = (char *) (MapViewOfFile(MapHandle , FILE_MAP_READ , 0 , 0 , 0));
        start = clock();
        SplitText(MapPointer , document);
        cout << clock() - start << endl;
        UnmapViewOfFile(MapPointer);
        CloseHandle(MapHandle);
        CloseHandle(hFile); 
    } while (true);
    std::cout << clock() - start << std::endl;
    delete[] name;
    delete[] word;
    return 0;
}

void SplitText(char * text ,
               Trie & document)
{
    static char * delimiters = " ,.?\xc4\x88\x97\x93\x94\x60\xa8\xe1\xb4\"\t:;!()!@#$%^&*";
    char * token = nullptr , * next = nullptr;
    token = strtok_s(text , delimiters , &next);
    while (token != nullptr)
    {
        document.insert(token);
        token = strtok_s(nullptr , delimiters , &next);
    }
}
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Remove the `SplitText` call. Run the above code. Do you still get access violation? If yes, `memset` the allocated variables to 0. Run the code again. If no access violation, call `SplitText`. If access violation, it's something in your `SplitText`.

Comment: @Brandon It seems like SplitText has problems with strtok_s.

Comment: Try: http://ideone.com/5KNncp  Change the `vector` to `Trie`.  It will work as shown. You should be checking if `MapPointer` is `NULL` before calling `SplitText`. I'm not sure about `strtok_s`. That's Microsoft Windows specific; the above works.